# Keep css active state after click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using psuedo classes and I'm having trouble figuring out how to interact with them using jquery.  I would think it's just like adding a class to an item, but if you look in my example, I'm not sure how to go about this.  I've done some searching, and maybe I'm just looking at it the wrong way.

When a button(`<span>`) is clicked it changes using :active, :before, active::before etc.

I want that button to stay clicked down after pushed. (until another `<span>` is clicked on)

```
    .lbButton { background-color:#eaa33d; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size:18px; text-decoration:none; color:#000; position:relative; padding:10px 20px; padding-right:50px; background-image: url('../images/nav_background1.png'); border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #ede8ba, 0px 5px 0px 0px #ab6c11, 0px 10px 5px #999; margin-left: 30px;cursor: pointer; }
    .lbButton:active {  top:3px;  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #ede8ba, 0px 2px 0px 0px #ab6c11, 0px 5px 3px #999; }
    .lbButton::before { background-color:#4e3108; background-image:url(http://heritageinncharlottesville.com/images/down_arrow.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center; content:""; width:20px; height:20px; position:absolute; right:15px; top:50%; margin-top:-9px; border-radius: 50%; box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #19120f, 0px 1px 0px #827066; }
    .lbButton:active::before { top:50%; margin-top:-12px; box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #827066, 0px 3px 0px #19120f, 0px 6px 3px #382e29; }
```

What is the way to go about this using jQuery?

[Click on Button, button looks pressed.  I would like to keep that state active after mouse release - and until the next one is pushed.](http://jsfiddle.net/stillb4llin/F4WBt/)

*Note:  I got this button online and copied the css. I've modified it to my color scheme*

Comment: You can do this by adding/removing classes. Take a look at toggleClass() http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: I understand changing classes, but using the :before / :after stuff is the wrench I'm going after.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.  I'm asking about keeping a css state active after clicking in an area, and then I can release the state when another area is clicked on.

This isn't a simple switch the class.

Comment: that's not how html, css and javascript work! you can't just *"freeze the active state on an element"*.

Comment: is there a way to keep a hover state somehow?

Comment: Yes, with JS. Use jQuery's .hover() and then addClass(). CSS pseudo class selectors do what they say they will do. There is no ::hover-and-freeze css pseudo class selector. Do you mind me asking why you are avoiding the very simple solutions using jQuery?

Comment: I've been avoiding it because I've just started diving into the psuedo classes...  and I'm trying to use them.  I put a bunch of time and then I ended up having to do it all over again.  Of course I didn't plan on doing what I was doing when I started out.

my html looks like this now..`<span id="al" class="inactiveButton">Assisted Living<img class="upArrow" src="../images/down_arrow.png" /></span>`  --  it has an `<img>` tag in it. It was so nice and clean before.

Answer (score 2):

It'd be better handled with jQuery toggling classes. The active pseudo-class wasn't meant for this type of functionality.

```
var spans = $('span.lbButton');

spans.on('click', function(){
    spans.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Given the previous snippet, apply the appropriate style definitions to the class `active`.

Comment: I understand that is a way to go about it, toggling classes like that.  Is there no way to keep that :active state on a mouseclick?

Comment: no, with CSS only, there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the styles to stick to the `span` until another `span` is clicked, I would suggest making a class for the `span` that has all the style you want when active, and then a default class for it for when the `span` is not active.

I'll assume that we have two classes here, `active-span` and `default-span`.  You seem to know your css, so you can define them.

jQuery:

```
$('span').click(function() {
    $('span').removeClass('active-span');
    $(this).addClass('active-span');
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/ZX7yg/

Comment: I appreciate that, but I'm not trying to change the classes like that. I'm trying to keep it in that :active state.  Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I know what you mean, I just am not sure if it can be done.